# Equations inside enumerate aligned on item's number

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, amsmath, align, enumerate

If I type

```
\begin{enumerate}    
    \item   
    \begin{align*}  
      eqn 1  
      eqn 2  
    \end{align*}  
\end{enumerate}
```

the label will appear on the first lines and the equations will appear on subsequent lines. How do I make it so that the equations begin on the same line as the enumerate label? Obviosly, I could manually adjust the location using `\vspace` and `\rule`, but is there a better way?

Comment: Are you sure you want to center the equations?

Comment: Yes, to do the same task without centering, I use \item $\begin{aligned}[t] equations \end{aligned}$

Comment: OK, but I'm still dubious about the result.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\Item[1][]{%
  \ifx\relax#1\relax  \item \else \item[#1] \fi
  \abovedisplayskip=0pt\abovedisplayshortskip=0pt~\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}    
\item foo
\Item  
    \begin{align*}  
      eqn 1  \\
      eqn 2  
    \end{align*}  
\Item[a)]  
    \begin{align*}  
      eqn 1  \\
      eqn 2  
    \end{align*}  
\item bar
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work for customized *item* like `\Item[<mylabel>]`. is it possible fix it?

Comment: see myedited answer

Comment: @Herbert great job .....

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287081/how-to-prevent-a-linebreak-before-align-equation-environment-in-itemize/287091?s=1|0.3679#287091

Comment: This affects all equation environments in the Item, not just the first. Is there any way to only remove the top margin on the first equation?

Comment: @AbrahamMurcianoBenzadon not only in that item, but in the whole remaining enumeration

Answer (score 18):

It is my personal taste, you might not agree with me. Here is my rule of thumb.

1. We know that the first line of all items of "list" (`enumerate`, `itemize`, etc) are left aligned.
2. So if the item starts with a multi-line aligned equation, use `aligned` environment (plus `t` passed to its optional argument) rather than `align*`. See my the second item in my example below. Using `align*` makes the equations centered so it breaks the nature of "list".
3. But if the item starts with a sentence, use `align*` environment. See my third item in the given example below. Using `align*` does not break the nature of "list".

Does it make sense?

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}% change it back to your own document class
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
% number 1
\item $E\neq mc^2$ is the correct formula.
% number 2
\item
$
\!
\begin{aligned}[t]
 (a+b)^2 
    &= (a+b)(a+b) && \text{by definition} \\
    &= a^2 +ab +ab +b^2 && \text{using FOIL steps}\\
    &= a^2 +2ab +b^2 && \text{simplified}
\end{aligned}
$ 
% number 3
\item Consider the following equations,
\begin{align*}
    \vec \nabla \cdot \vec{B} &= 0\\
    \vec \nabla \times \vec{E} &= -\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t}
\end{align*}
% number
\item $y=mx+c$ is a street line.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I use `align*` because it is possible *break* the alignment across the pages (with `\allowdisplaybreaks`) unlike `aligned` that produces *unbreakable* boxes.

Comment: Why do you put the \! ?