# How to prevent a linebreak before align/equation environment in itemize?

Tags: line-breaking, align, itemize

The following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item 
\begin{align}
a&=b\\
&=d
\end{align}
\item 
\begin{equation}
a=b\\
=d
\end{equation}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

How to avoid the linebreak after the bullet and have the equations (1 and 3) begin on the same line (with the bullet)? I should perhaps emphasize that I want to preserve the numbering of the equations.

Comment: I think you want the `aligned` environment, used as `$\begin{aligned}[t]....$`

Comment: @cmhughes I've already tried this (sorry, should have mentioned) and it does not preserve the equation numbering, does it?

Comment: looks quite a lot like: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58141/equations-inside-enumerate-aligned-on-items-number

Comment: @cmhughes Yes, and an answer is there. What shall I do to connect the two questions?

Comment: @wondering -- if you've identified an answer, you can vote to close your question as a duplicate.  i'll start that process.

Answer (score 3):

One can eliminate the `\vspace*{-\baselineskip}` from the other solution by using `\abovedisplayskip=-\baselineskip` instead.  Note that `equation` uses `\abovedisplayshortskip`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}

\rule{1pt}{43\baselineskip}% force pagebreak

\begin{itemize}% changes below are local to this environment
\abovedisplayskip=-\baselineskip
\belowdisplayskip=0pt
\abovedisplayshortskip=-\baselineskip
\belowdisplayshortskip=0pt
\item\begin{align}
a&=b\\
&=d
\end{align}
\item\begin{equation}
a=b\\
=d
\end{equation}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image: itemized equations]

Comment: Thank you. However, I still have a problem with the multline environment, for which your solution (and the [other](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58145/66983), mentioned in the comment by cmhughes)  does not work. Sure, it is not mentioned in the question, but if you knew how to deal with it, too, it would be very helpful.

Comment: I modified my solution based on the referenced solution and page breaking experiments.