# Write2Latex output list items not on one line

Tags: lists

I don't understand why the output of `write2latex` OpenOffice addon makes this kind of list:

This is in the preamble:

```
\newcommand\liststyleLii{%
\renewcommand\theenumi{\Roman{enumi}}
\renewcommand\theenumii{\Roman{enumii}}
\renewcommand\theenumiii{\Roman{enumiii}}
\renewcommand\theenumiv{\Roman{enumiv}}
\renewcommand\labelenumi{\theenumi.}
\renewcommand\labelenumii{\theenumii.}
\renewcommand\labelenumiii{\theenumiii.}
\renewcommand\labelenumiv{\theenumiv.}
}
```

And this is in the document:

```
\section{Binomische Formeln}
  \liststyleLii
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item \begin{align*} (a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2 \end{align*}
      \item \begin{align*} (a-b)^2=a^2-2ab+b^2 \end{align*}
      \item \begin{align*} (a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2 \end{align*}
    \end{enumerate}
```

the outpus is:

[image: the Lii list]

and I would like to have the "II" on one line with the "(a-b)..."

Actualy all the bullets on one line with the equation.  I don't know which package is enabling that liststyle

Comment: By inserting the mathematical environment `\begin{align} ... `\end{align}` you are inserting a skip of white space before the equation, which leads to the distortion.    Just use a inline math environment.  Please, insert a full MWE (Minimal Working Example) from `\documentclass}` to `\end{document}`.  It'll save us the typing burden.

Comment: although use of a display environment here, where the equations are each only one line is incorrect, there *is* a mechanism to make this work.  see [Equations inside `enumerate` aligned on item's number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58141).  (possible duplicate?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mathematical environment `\begin{align*} ... \end{align*}` inserts white space above the environment.  This breaks the alignment, you are after.  Take a normal inline mathematical environment as for example `$...$`.

This should do the trick:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article} 

\usepackage[german]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\newcommand\liststyleLii{%
\renewcommand\theenumi{\Roman{enumi}}
\renewcommand\theenumii{\Roman{enumii}}
\renewcommand\theenumiii{\Roman{enumiii}}
\renewcommand\theenumiv{\Roman{enumiv}}
\renewcommand\labelenumi{\theenumi.}
\renewcommand\labelenumii{\theenumii.}
\renewcommand\labelenumiii{\theenumiii.}
\renewcommand\labelenumiv{\theenumiv.}
}
\liststyleLii

\begin{document}
\section{Binomische Formeln}
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2 $
      \item $(a-b)^2=a^2-2ab+b^2 $
      \item $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2  $
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Here is the result:

[image: Binomische Formeln]