# Aligning formulas inside enumerate

Tags: horizontal-alignment, enumerate, gather

I have an ordered list (`enumerate`) each item of which is a numbered formula. I am using a `gather` environment.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
The following conditions are true:
\begin{enumerate}
\item \begin{gather}
    x^2 \ge 0,
\end{gather}
\item \begin{gather}
    x^2 \ge 0,
\end{gather}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

But the formulas appear in the center of the next line producing one empty line.

[image]
How can I get rid of the empty lines and align the formulas to the left? Formula numbers must stay on the right. I would like to stick to the `gather` environment if possible, because I find it very convenient for my purposes.

Comment: Why do you the T2A encoding if you only use english?

Comment: Why use `enumerate` if the equations are numbered?

Comment: @Skillmon: There might be text in addition to an equation in each item, and the list numbering might be independent of the equation numbering.

Comment: @Bernard, I use other languages apart from English as well. This is just a MWE.

Comment: this question might be helpful: [Equations inside `enumerate` aligned on item's number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58141)  (possible duplicate)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution: I define a new environment, `Lgather` (`L` is for  both list and left), with the help of package `nccmath`, which defines a `fleqn` environment (inside this environment, equations are left-aligned) and a `\useshortskip` command, which in practice makes the spacing between text and displayed equation equal to `\baselineskip`, so I only had to neutralise it with a `\vspace*{-\baselineskip}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
\newenvironment{Lgather}{\useshortskip\leavevmode\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\fleqn\gather}{\endgather\endfleqn}

\begin{document}

The following conditions are true:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item 
    \begin{Lgather}
    x^2 \ge 0,
 \end{Lgather}
\item 
    \begin{Lgather}
    x^2 \ge 0,
    \end{Lgather}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Brillant but coding is not understandable by plain Latex users.

Comment: @pzorba75: I've added an explanation for `\useshortskip`. Is it clearer?

Comment: @Bernard : For sure, this explanation is useful. But I still remain unable to write such expressions from  my own.

Comment: @pzorba75 `\newenvironment` lets you define a new `environment` it takes 3 mandatory arguments being the environment's name, the code to be executed at `\begin` and the code to be executed at `\end`. The `\begin` part issues `\useshortskip` and a negative vertical skip of one `\baselineskip`. After that it starts two environments without using `\begin` namely `fleqn` and `gather`, both are ended in the end branch with `\endfleqn` and `\endgather` (the code to be used at `\begin` is stored in a macro with the environment's name as its name, the `\end` in `\end<name>`).

Comment: @pzorba75 does that help?

Comment: @Skillmon : Sure it helps;  Why gather following fleqn is needed as there is only a one line expression in fleqn?

Comment: @pzorba75 because `fleqn` is not a math environment but an environment in which every display math environment should be left aligned. You could use `equation` instead of `gather` for example, but you need to use a math environment.