# How to define a starred custom gather new environment

Tags: math-mode, environments, starred-version, csname, gather

I'm writing a file which I need the equations inside the gather environment to not be numbered.
I was able to see the normal version ([this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/445996/aligning-formulas-inside-enumerate), which works great:

```
\newenvironment{Lgather}{\useshortskip\leavevmode\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\fleqn\gather}{\endgather\endfleqn}
```

But when I try to create the starred version, so the equations will not be numbered (that 1.1, 1.2... thing), it fails:

```
\newenvironment{Lgather}{\csname \useshortskip\leavevmode\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\fleqn\gather*\endcsname}{\csname \endgather*\endfleqn \endcsname}
```

I even tried

```
\newenvironment{Lgather}{\useshortskip\leavevmode\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\fleqn\gather*}{\endgather*\endfleqn}
```

But it also fails...

Thank you very, very much in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Which kind of sorcerer are you, sir? Works perfectly. Super nice and clean. Thank you very, very much!

Comment: Environments are always expanded using `\csname ...\endcsname`, so including a * in the name is legal.  In other words, use `\newenvironment{Lgather*}{...}{...}` with a completely different definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't require equation numbering, you might employ a `gathered` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\noindent
The following conditions are true:
\begin{enumerate}
\item $\begin{gathered}[t]
       x^2 \ge 0 \\
       x^2-y^2 \le 0 
       \end{gathered} $
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

If you have lots of instances of such `gathered` environments, you may want to simplify the process of entering them by setting up a macro, say,

```
\newcommand{\Lgather}[1]{\ensuremath{\begin{gathered}[t] #1 \end{gathered}}}
```

and then entering the equations as follows:

```
\Lgather{x^2 \ge 0 \\ x^2-y^2 \le 0}
```

Comment: Beautiful. Absolutely beautiful. Yes, I am doing an math exercises pdf and I will use this command over and over again. It gets much, much better. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

One can deduce it from the `\meaning\gather`, but substituting `\st@arredtrue` for `\st@rredfalse`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,nccmath}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{Lgather}{\useshortskip\leavevmode
   \vspace*{-\baselineskip}\fleqn\start@gather\st@rredtrue}
  {\endgather\endfleqn}
\makeatother
\begin{Lgather}
a =1\\
b=2\\c=3
\end{Lgather}

\meaning \gather
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very clever this idea of using this `\st@arredtrue`. Going to save this for next environments where I need the starred version. Thank you very much!

Comment: @BrunoAndrade I can't guarantee it will work in other circumstances, but perhaps across the `amsmath` environments.  In any event, remember `\meaning` to explore such things.