# Align inside enumerate

Tags: align, enumerate, itemize

Is it possible to align `\item`s content inside `enumerate`environment?

My expected output is:

[image]

Which I got manually, (adjusting with `\hspace`)

These answers:

[Aligning formulas inside enumerate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/445996/aligning-formulas-inside-enumerate)

[Equations inside enumerate aligned on item's number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58141/equations-inside-enumerate-aligned-on-items-number)

don't respond my question because they try to use align inside the `\item`s

Neither [Enumerate inside align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43722/enumerate-inside-align)

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item $X$ integrable $\Longrightarrow E[X|\mathcal{A}_1]$ integrable y $E[E[X|\mathcal{A}_1]]=E[X]$
\item $\mathcal{A}_1=\{\emptyset,\Omega\} \Longrightarrow E[X|\mathcal{A}_1](\omega)=E[X],\ \forall \omega\in\Omega$
\item $\mathcal{A}_1=\mathcal{A}\Longrightarrow E[X|\mathcal{A}_1]=X \ c.s.[P_1]$ 
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably the only thing you can do here is to make boxes of the same size to wrap the part before `\Longrightarrow`. Do be honest, I don't see the point in aligning here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming this is not the only such display in your document, you might use `eqparbox` facilities.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\newcounter{mathenum}

\newenvironment{mathenum}
 {\begin{enumerate}\stepcounter{mathenum}}
 {\end{enumerate}}
\newcommand{\mathenumitem}[3]{%
  \item
  \eqmakebox[@@\themathenum @A@][l]{#1}%
  ${}\Longrightarrow{}$%
  \eqmakebox[@@\themathenum @B@][l]{#2}%
  \quad#3%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mathenum}
\mathenumitem{$X$ integrable}
             {$E[X|\mathcal{A}_1]$ integrable y $E[E[X|\mathcal{A}_1]]=E[X]$}
             {}
\mathenumitem{$\mathcal{A}_1=\{\emptyset,\Omega\}$}
             {$E[X|\mathcal{A}_1](\omega)=E[X],\ \forall \omega\in\Omega$}
             {}
\mathenumitem{$\mathcal{A}_1=\mathcal{A}$}
             {$E[X|\mathcal{A}_1]=X$}
             {c.s.$[P_1]$}
\end{mathenum}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A slightly different version where the central symbol (which is supposed to be an arrow) can vary:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\newcounter{mathenum}

\newenvironment{mathenum}
 {\begin{enumerate}\stepcounter{mathenum}}
 {\end{enumerate}}
\newcommand{\mathenumitem}[4]{%
  \item
  \eqmakebox[@@\themathenum @A@][l]{#1}%
  \eqmakebox[@@\themathenum @B@][c]{${}#2{}$}%
  \eqmakebox[@@\themathenum @C@][l]{#3}%
  \quad#4%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mathenum}
\mathenumitem{$X$ integrable}
             {\Longrightarrow}
             {$E[X|\mathcal{A}_1]$ integrable y $E[E[X|\mathcal{A}_1]]=E[X]$}
             {}
\mathenumitem{$\mathcal{A}_1=\{\emptyset,\Omega\}$}
             {\Longleftrightarrow}
             {$E[X|\mathcal{A}_1](\omega)=E[X],\ \forall \omega\in\Omega$}
             {}
\mathenumitem{$\mathcal{A}_1=\mathcal{A}$}
             {\Longleftarrow}
             {$E[X|\mathcal{A}_1]=X$}
             {c.s.$[P_1]$} 
\end{mathenum}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `newenvironment` you defined is so useful. Is it possible to have different symbols in each line? For example, `Longright arrow` in the first one, and `iff` in the second one

Comment: @Á.Iborra Add other arguments along the same lines. You will probably need another label for `\eqmakebox`. I added a sketch.

Comment: First time using `\eqmakebox`, do you know why can't I nest `mathenum`  into `tcolorbox` theorem?

Comment: @Á.Iborra This warrants a new question with the details. My crystal ball is under maintainance. ;-)

Comment: It worked well, typo mistake. Your answer was so clear that I asked again before looking for fails. Thank you for the details

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't persist with use of `enumerate`. Numbers can be writen for example in `alignat*` examle encapsulated in `fleqn` environment defined in the `nccmath` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nccmath}
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{fleqn}
\begin{alignat*}{3}
&1.\ X \text{ integrable}\hspace{-11em} 
    &\quad&   \Longrightarrow E[X|\mathcal{A}_1] \text{ integrable y }
                    E[E[X|\mathcal{A}_1]]=E[X]                      \\
&2.\ \mathcal{A}_1 =\{\emptyset,\Omega\} 
    &&   \Longrightarrow E[X|\mathcal{A}_1](\omega)=E[X],\ \forall \omega\in\Omega   
                                                                    \\
&3.\ \mathcal{A}_1 =\mathcal{A}
    &&   \Longrightarrow E[X|\mathcal{A}_1]=X \ c.s.[P_1]        \tag{$c.s.[P_1]$}   
\end{alignat*}
\end{fleqn}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)