# How to add new environment without transferring formula to the next line?

Tags: align, environments

I'm trying to add environment `align` inside of `enumerate`, and this attempting leads to transferring formula which is not needed. How do I leave the formula on the place?

```
\item \begin{align*}  C\left(z\right) = \Biggl[
&  \prod\limits_{\ell=1}^{m} \frac{E_\ell\left(z_\ell\right)}{E_{\ell-
1}\left(z_\ell\right)}\Biggl] \! \Biggl[ \prod\limits_{\ell=1}^{m}
\frac{\prod_{u \in L_{z        _\ell}}\left(-u\right)^N\prod_{v \in
R_{z_\ell}} \left(v+1\right)^{L-N}}{\Delta\left(R_{z_\ell}; L_{z_\ell}
\right)} \Biggl] \\ 
&  \times \Biggl[\prod\limits_{\ell=2}^{m} \frac{z_{\ell-1}^L}{z_{\ell-1}^L-
z_\ell^L}\Biggl] \Biggl[\prod\limits_{\ell=2}^m\frac{\Delta\left(R_{z_\ell};
L_{z_{\ell-1}}\right)}{\prod_{u \in L_{z_{\ell-1}}}\left(-u\right)^N
\prod_{v \in R_{z_\ell}}\left(v+1\right)^{L-N}} \Biggl] 
\end{align*}
\end{enumerate}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX!

Comment: Relevant: [Equations inside `enumerate` aligned on item's number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58141)

Answer (score 1):

Use  `aligned[t]` in a simple $...$:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item $ \begin{aligned}[t]\displaystyle C\left(z\right) = \Biggl[ & \prod\limits_{\ell=1}^{m} \frac{E_\ell\left(z_\ell\right)}{E_{\ell-1}\left(z_\ell\right)}\Biggl] ! \Biggl[ \prod\limits_{\ell=1}^{m}\frac{\prod_{u \in L_{z_\ell}}\left(-u\right)^N\prod_{v \in R_{z_\ell}} \left(v+1\right)^{L-N}}{\Delta\left(R_{z_\ell}; L_{z_\ell}\right)} \Biggl] \\
 & \times \Biggl[\prod\limits_{\ell=2}^{m} \frac{z_{\ell-1}^L}{z_{\ell-1}^L-z_\ell^L}\Biggl] \Biggl[\prod\limits_{\ell=2}^m\frac{\Delta\left(R_{z_\ell};L_{z_{\ell-1}}\right)}{\prod_{u \in L_{z_{\ell-1}}}\left(-u\right)^N\prod_{v \in R_{z_\ell}}\left(v+1\right)^{L-N}} \Biggl] \end{aligned} $
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I use instead another simple solution using "*two separate codes*". For the item and for the first part of the formula, I have used  `$\displaystyle ......$`; after I have used the classic ambient `\align*`. You can observe that for several and different items there are not any changes for the style of any long equations.
There is also an advantage: `=` and `\times` have a vertical alignment as from screenshot.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item  $\displaystyle C\left(z\right) = \Biggl[
\prod\limits_{\ell=1}^{m} \frac{E_\ell\left(z_\ell\right)}{E_{\ell-
1}\left(z_\ell\right)}\Biggl] \! \Biggl[ \prod\limits_{\ell=1}^{m}
\frac{\prod_{u \in L_{z_\ell}}\left(-u\right)^N\prod_{v \in
R_{z_\ell}} \left(v+1\right)^{L-N}}{\Delta\left(R_{z_\ell}; L_{z_\ell}
\right)} \Biggl]$
\begin{align*}
&  \times \Biggl[\prod\limits_{\ell=2}^{m} \frac{z_{\ell-1}^L}{z_{\ell-1}^L-
z_\ell^L}\Biggl] \Biggl[\prod\limits_{\ell=2}^m\frac{\Delta\left(R_{z_\ell};
L_{z_{\ell-1}}\right)}{\prod_{u \in L_{z_{\ell-1}}}\left(-u\right)^N
\prod_{v \in R_{z_\ell}}\left(v+1\right)^{L-N}} \Biggl] 
\end{align*}   
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```