# amsmath equation numbering or equations in lists

Tags: equations, align, amsmath, indentation, itemize

I want to list equations with a bullet point in front of the equations. The two ways I thought of to make this possible are either to set the equation numbering style to a bullet point or to put the equations simply into a list.

The problem is just that I've got multiline equations (not in the multiline environment but with multiple lines) and when putting these equations into lists, the label (in my case the bulletpoint) of the list is positioned a bit weird (see the MWE and the picture below).

Therefore I made an equation numbering style with bulletpoints instead of numbers and number only the first line of the equation, but now the space between the label and equation is too large (should be as large as the space between label and item in a list.

Is it possible to specify the (horizontal) spacing between label and equation? Or other option, is it possible so set the label of the list to the first line of the equation?

Edit: I found out that the equation number is set on the most left place (whith the leqno option) and the space to the equation is set indirectly by the `mathindent` length.
But there arises a new question, can the mathindent length be set individual for the different environments?

Answers to either one of the three questions would help me, since the answer to one of them should solve my issue.

```
\documentclass[leqno]{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\setlength{\mathindent}{\labelset} %this is just a workarround to specify as least space as possible but still get the number and the equation into the same line
\addtolength{\mathindent}{1.6ex} 

\begin{document}
%either
\begin{itemize} %here the bulletpoint sadly is in the middle of the two lines, not in front of the first one
    \item
    \begin{align*}
        line1\\
        line2
    \end{align*}

    \item
    \begin{align*}
        line1\\
        line2
    \end{align*}
\end{itemize}

%or

\begin{align*} %this looks good, but I'd like so set the \mathindent specific only for some equations, the other equations should be indented differently. And maybe there is a more elegant way to do this than the way I'm doing this right now.
    line1 \tag*{$\bullet$}\\
    line2
%
    line1 \tag*{$\bullet$}\\
    line2
\end{align*}

\end{documet}
```

[image: picture of the MWE]

Comment: This is not quite clear to me. You say the first line should be numbered. At the right margin (the default) or at the left margin?. And the other lines introduced like items  in an itemize environment – should the bullets be at the left margin, or simply near the formulæ in these other lines, but nevertheless, the whole thing be centred in the text width?

Comment: In the end this should look like a listing of multiple equations. Therefore the equation numbering has to be on the left (if using the equation tags for the listing icons/bulletpoints) (the equations themselves should not be numbered). And the space between bulletpoint and equation should always be approx the amount of space between bulletpoint and text in a normal list.

Comment: Does this make thinks more clear?

Comment: How or where is `\labelset` defined?

Comment: Does `\begin{itemize} \item\quad $\begin{aligned}[t] line1\\ line2 \end{aligned}$ \end{itemize}` satisfy your formatting requirements?

Comment: One of these questions may help, depending on what you want the horizontal position to be: [Vertical alignment of `align*` in `enumerate`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9394), [Equations inside `enumerate` aligned on item's number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58141)

Comment: I found `\labelset` to be defined by itemize (should be the length between label/bulletpoint and text, but I'm not sure on that). With the suggestion of inline formulas: Hm to be honest I'm trying to get this working in a not inline environment (since typesetting matrices in inline mode is not that good).

Comment: And with the second suggestion, at the first link they solve this with inline math mode as well :/ But at the second link one suggested setting ``\abovedisplayskip`` and ``\abovedisplayshortskip`` both to ``-\baselineskip``. This helps, however in my document the label of the itemize env is still a bit too high (setting this with an absolute offset will cause problems, when changing e.g. fontsize)