# Bullets not aligned with equation

Tags: equations, itemize

I want to align the bullet to the equation but for some reason the equation renders a line underneath the bullet. Here is my code

```
\begin{itemize} 
       \item[\textcolor{blue}{\textbullet}]
         \begin{equation*}%blue
             (w^{\dagger_1})^{\dagger_0} = (\overline{x}+\overline{y}\varepsilon)^{\dagger_0} = \overline{x}+\overline{y}\varepsilon = (x+y\varepsilon)^{\dagger_1} = (w^{\dagger_0})^{\dagger_1} = w^{\dagger_1}
        \end{equation*}
         
         \item[\textcolor{red}{\textbullet}]
         \begin{equation*}%red
             (w^{\dagger_2})^{\dagger_0} = (x-y\varepsilon)^{\dagger_0} = x-y\varepsilon = (x+y\varepsilon)^{\dagger_2} = (w^{\dagger_0})^{\dagger_2} = w^{\dagger_2}
        \end{equation*}
\end{itemize}
```

Here is the image
[image: Output]

Here is the desired output
[image]

Comment: Welcome! Do you have numbered equations in your document? If so, is the number on the right or on the left?

Comment: @egreg no numbers, only bullets

Comment: @eggreg yes there are numbered equations and they're on the left. please disregard my previous comment

Comment: This previous question is relevant: [Equations inside `enumerate` aligned on item's number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58141)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use inline math mode instead of display math mode.

A separate matter: I would also use `\bar{x}` instead of `\overline{x}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{xcolor,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize} 
\item[\textcolor{blue}{\textbullet}] \quad
       $(w^{\dagger_1})^{\dagger_0} 
       = (\bar{x}+\bar{y}\varepsilon)^{\dagger_0} 
       = \bar{x}+\bar{y}\varepsilon 
       = (x+y\varepsilon)^{\dagger_1} 
       = (w^{\dagger_0})^{\dagger_1} = w^{\dagger_1}$
         
\item[\textcolor{red}{\textbullet}] \quad
       $(w^{\dagger_2})^{\dagger_0} 
       = (x-y\varepsilon)^{\dagger_0} 
       = x-y\varepsilon 
       = (x+y\varepsilon)^{\dagger_2} 
       = (w^{\dagger_0})^{\dagger_2} = w^{\dagger_2}$
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: No `\displaystyle`?

Comment: @JohnKormylo - In general, yes. For the code at hand, though, it makes no difference, exept for a `1pt` shift in the height of the superscript terms.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you'd prefer using `gather` and `\tag`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

These are tagged equations, with some more text to emulate
some real text, which this isn't
\begin{gather}
\tag*{\textcolor{blue}{\textbullet}}
(w^{\dagger_1})^{\dagger_0}
= (\overline{x}+\overline{y}\varepsilon)^{\dagger_0} 
= \overline{x}+\overline{y}\varepsilon 
= (x+y\varepsilon)^{\dagger_1}
= (w^{\dagger_0})^{\dagger_1} = w^{\dagger_1}
\\
\tag*{\textcolor{red}{\textbullet}}
(w^{\dagger_2})^{\dagger_0}
= (x-y\varepsilon)^{\dagger_0}
= x-y\varepsilon
= (x+y\varepsilon)^{\dagger_2}
= (w^{\dagger_0})^{\dagger_2}
= w^{\dagger_2}
\end{gather}
These are standard equations, with some more text to emulate
some real text, which this isn't
\begin{equation}
1+1=2
\end{equation}
These are standard equations, with some more text to emulate
some real text, which this isn't

\end{document}
```

[image]